# Revert "Add edit" of the track, after CMD+K in Adobe Premiere CC 2017

Tags: premiere

Is there a way to revert "Add edit" on the track? When I press CMD+K on my track (audio or video), it will be split into two tracks. Sometimes I "Add edit" by mistake and realize it after few steps where press "Back" several times no best way and i want just connect together two pieces of the same track. Is it possible? For sure I can mark all pieces and combine them into group but i want have one whole track instead of organized group.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you can't use undo to remove the edit point? Or that you want to remove the edit point without undoing all your other actions?

Answer (score 4):

On Windows:
Hold CTRL and right click the split itself. Then click "Join Through Edits".

Mac should be similar I guess.

Comment: on Mac use `cmd`. Or right-click on either platform. You can also select the join and hit `delete`.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thank you guys. Still can't  join tracks which are not strict sequence, but think it is logically. But where end of one are begin of second joined good.